# How to upload and retrieve images in a spring MVC web application

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

How do I upload an image through a form in a JSP page and also retrieve it? Say, I have a model class and want to add a field which corresponds to the image file with appropriate getters and setters and later wish to save the model class. I am using hibernate for the mapping.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet @akuma8

Comment: example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

Comment: Let me check it . Thanks @akuma8